# How to scroll/center code in VSCode Vim if there are no blank lines to scroll to?

Tags: vscodevim

How to scroll like picture on the right?

[image: problem]
[image]

I tried using `CTRL` + `D` which scrolls through lines but if there are no lines, like after line 87 I cannot scroll/center my screen. I was thinking I could insert bunch of empty lines but VSCode when saving it removes all those empty lines. After looking through VSCode shortcuts I found that if you press `fn` + `CMD` + `Arrow Keys` it does what I want but it scrolls out of proportion.

So my question is that is there a built-in solution for this in Vim or in VSCode or do I still need to use my mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my noob question, I was asking the wrong question, it should have been "How to scroll w/o moving your cursor in VSCode VIM?". Now I know, CTRL+Y for scrolling up CTRL + E and CTRL + Y for scrolling down.